# Issue with logging output of batch execution

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file `batchfile.bat` that has some 7zip and Mysql operations. I have a second batch file to execute this called `executor.bat` . The `executor.bat` file only has the below code

```
.\batchfile.bat >>output.txt
```

So i expect all execution output to be written into `output.txt`. However, when i double click on `executor.bat`, i see the command prompt open and some mysql error messages, are coming on this command prompt instead of moving into the `output.txt` file. On the other hand, i can see 7-zip command line output getting captured in the `output.txt` file.

How can i further redirect the messages on command prompt to go into the `output.txt` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>>` redirector appends a `STDOUT` (text output) to the target file, but `mysql` error messages are sent to `STDERR` (error text output). To redirect both  output and errors to one file, use next syntax:

```
.\batchfile.bat >>output.txt 2>>&1
```

FYI, all numeric handles are:

```
STDIN     = 0  Keyboard input
STDOUT    = 1  Text output
STDERR    = 2  Error text output
UNDEFINED = 3-9
```

Answer (score 1):

Error messages get sent to the command prompt through a different output pipe than regular messages.

Try updating executor.bat to
`.\batchfile.bat >>output.txt 2>>output.txt`

Comment: the file is not executing. Is there a typo in the statement? I tried .\batchfile.bat 1>>output.txt 2>>output.txt too, but no luck